# Read from request method in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a Node.js script that converts HTML files to ENML (Evernote Markup Language).

Now this script correctly converts an existing HTML file to the desired ENML output. Now, I have the following question:

Client will be sending an HTML file in JSON format. How do I listen for all incoming requests, take the JSON object, convert to ENML, and write back the response to the original request?

My code for this is as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var html = require('enmlOfHtml');
var contents = '';
var contents1 = '';
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8', function(err, html1){
    html.ENMLOfHTML(html1, function(err, ENML){ //using Enml-js npm
        contents1=ENML;
    });
});
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
      res.write(contents1);
    }).listen(4567, "127.0.0.1");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the client will make POST requests to your server. Here is how you could get the send information:

```
var processRequest = function(req, callback) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        callback(qs.parse(body));
    });
}

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    processRequest(req, function(clientData) {
        html.ENMLOfHTML(clientData, function(err, ENML){ //using Enml-js npm
            contents1 = ENML;
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.write(JSON.stringify(contents1));
        });
    }); 
}).listen(4567, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Node's [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) module.

```
request('http://www.example.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```